# Improve the speed of the program to O(n), log(n) or possibly O(1)

Tags: java, big-o

Is there a way to improve the speed of this program? I was thinking recursion, but with the test cases it might crash the program with an overflow on the stack.

```
class BetterUF extends UF {

    public BetterUF(int size) {
        super(size);
    }

    // Determine if nodes are in different trees 
    public boolean inSameSet(int a, int b) {
        Integer root1 = find(a);     // Find root of node a
        Integer root2 = find(b);     // Find root of node b
        return root1.intValue() == root2.intValue();       // Compare roots
    }

    // Merge two subtrees 
    public void union(int a, int b) {
        Integer root1 = find(a);     // Find root of node a
        Integer root2 = find(b);     // Find root of node b
        if (root1.intValue() != root2.intValue())
            array[root2] = root1; // Merge
    }

    // return the root of curr's tree 
    public Integer find(Integer curr) {
        if (array[curr] == -1)
            return curr;  // At root
        while (array[curr] != -1)
            curr = array[curr];
        return curr;
    }
}



  abstract class UF {
    protected Integer [] array;      // Node array

    public UF(int size) {
    array = new Integer[size];   // Create node array
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        array[i] = new Integer(-1); // Initially every node is a root
    }

    /** Determine if nodes are in different trees */
    public abstract boolean inSameSet(int a, int b); 

    /** Merge two subtrees */
    public abstract void union(int a, int b);

    /** @return The root of curr's tree */
    public abstract Integer find(Integer curr);

    // Use to print the disjoint sets
    String printUFSets() {
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer(1000);
    out.append("{ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        boolean left_brace_printed = false;
        // Anything that has i as its representative will be printed
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        int k = find(j);
        if (k == i && !left_brace_printed) {
            out.append(" { " + j + " ");
            left_brace_printed = true;
        }
        else if (k == i)
            out.append(" " + j + " ");
        }
        if (left_brace_printed)
        out.append("} ") ;
    }
    out.append(" }") ;

    return out.toString();
    }

    // Use to print the parent pointers
    String printUFTrees() {
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer(1000);
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        out.append(array[i] + " ");
    }

    return out.toString();
    }

    // Return the average number of nodes on a path in the tree
    float avgNodesOnPath () {
    return 0.0f;
    }
}
```

What do you guys think to speed this up?

Comment: _Which_ of the three operations are you looking to speed up?

Comment: What's this do, in words? What test cases? Why do you think it can be improved? That find method looks like a linear search

Comment: If you want recursion and no risk of a stack overflow use a loop instead of a method call if possible.

Comment: What does the code do? This is far from being complete enough to be optimized at all. Post the relevant code. I.e. the implementation of the forest itself.

Comment: I added the other class